# JDBC control don't see after install last Extlib

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have installed last version 853.20120605-0921 of ExtLib...
In designer I don't see under folder **Data Access** the JDBC control...
Have anyone any suggest?

On the server after the command **tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib** seem correctly all:

07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  Framework is launched.
[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  id State       Bundle

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  10 ACTIVE
   com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.sbt_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  11 ACTIVE

com.ibm.xsp.extlib_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM               Fragments=13

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  12 ACTIVE
  com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  13 RESOLVED
 com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.oauth_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM               Master=11

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  14 ACTIVE
  com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  16 ACTIVE
 com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  19 RESOLVED
com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational.derby_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  20 ACTIVE
   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  23 ACTIVE
   com.ibm.xsp.extlibx_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  28 <>
 com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.core_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  29 ACTIVE
   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  30 RESOLVED
 com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.controls_8.5.3.20120605-0921

[07567:00002-3026265808] 06/18/2012 12:17:19 PM  31 ACTIVE
   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_8.5.3.20120605-0921

Have someone any suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx to all,
I have found the solution.
I have disabled all extlib, one to one and restart the designer....
After I reinstall from UpdateSite...and work!

Tnx..seem that the procedure require is remove one entry of ExtLib one at a time.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the extension library in your Notes/Domino Designer client by following this?

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Installing_the_OpenNTF_update_site_in_Domino_Designer_ddxl853

You need to have the extension library installed in Domino Designer in order to see the extension library controls.

Comment: Yes I have follow this link....But in Designer for example in the database XPagesJDBC.nsf I see this warning error:
"com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.library" the library are not installed in Lotus Domino Designer. Including there librarues and controls form these libraries in your Xpages will cause errors in your application at runtime...

I have follow step by step the procedure for installation

Comment: Do you see the "Extended Component Library for XPages" plug-ins when you go to Help -> About IBM Lotus Domino Designer -> Plug-in Details?

Comment: Yes! I see all Plugin ...I see the icon unsigned...is this the problem?

Comment: I see the unsigned icon too so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Extended Component Library for XPages in your application yet? The components will not appear until you do.  Go to your app's Application Properties, go to the advanced tab, and in the XPages Library box, click the "com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.library" checkbox. Open your XPage in designer, and you should now see the components.